# Twitter Bootstrap: CSS not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Here's the website: http://alweso.2ap.pl/koniugator/trarara.html

This is not the first website I'm making using Bootstrap, so I really don't know why it's not working. All files are in place, here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Polish Verb Conjugator</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
      <form action="owacewac.php" method="post">
Conjugate: <input type="text" name="verb"><br>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try this code: <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> and see if it works, I think you're linking the wrong file.

Comment: The `css/bootstrap.min.css` doesn't exists on the server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your css file is not found, error 404. Change this line and should be ok:

`<link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

(relate path was wrong)

Comment: I was missing the rel="stylesheet" part, which caused my styles not to load.

Answer (score 2):

Just to help anyone searching and searching.

To solve my issue I had to make sure there were no errors in the browsers javascript console. If you have an error there it can make ALL your javascript (bootstrap stuff) not work. So check the console! I had some kind of error in bootstrap-tooltips. Messed EVERYTHING up.

```
Removed
//= require bootstrap-tooltips
```

Everything works now.

Comment: Your console suggestion helped me find why my .css was disconnected.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome console says :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

then your css file is in a directory other than this

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

UPDATE

your css file is here : http://alweso.2ap.pl/css/bootstrap.min.css

then use

```
<link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 1):

The browser cannot find `css/bootstrap.min.css`. Most probably you haven't uploaded it yet, since the browser finds `js/bootstrap.min.js`, and navigating to http://alweso.2ap.pl/koniugator/css throws a 404 Page Not Found.

The server response headers indicate that you use nginx, which should properly serve this files if they were there. If you insist that the files are uploaded, you have to check the nginx configuration to make sure no strange rules for css files exist.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I made a mistake in my .htaccess file by using a different website address.  The night before I had worked long hours and mis-uploaded another website's .htaccess file.  Checking for errors with Mozilla console helped to find the error.